# Fast convolution of sparse functions

Tags: algorithms, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Z}$ be a step function with at most $k$ discontinuities, at given rationals $a_1<a_2<\dotsc<a_k$. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Z}$ be given as a linear combination of at most $k$ delta functions $\delta_{b_i}$, $b_i\in \mathbb{Q}$. Can we compute $(F\ast g)(n)$ for $l$ consecutive integers $n=n_0+1,\dotsc,n_0+l$ in time roughly linear to $\max(k,l)$ (say, $O(\max(k,l) \log \max(k,l))$)?

In the case that I am truly interested in, all of $a_1,\dotsc,a_k,b_1,\dotsc,b_k$ can be written as fractions with denominator $Q$, where $Q$ is much larger than $k$ and $l$ but not enormous ($\log Q$ is small). In this case, it seems plausible to me that one could adapt a Fourier-transform-based method. Still, I'd be surprised if the question hasn't been considered before, so I'd appreciate references (or any indication of how to solve the problem more cleanly or efficiently).

Comment: We can obviously reduce the problem to one where $a_1,\dotsc,a_k,b_1,\dotsc,b_k$ are integers, and we wish to compute $(F\ast g)(n Q)$ for $n=n_0+1,\dotsc,n_0+l$. I believe I can see how to use a modified Cooley-Tukey method (divide-and-conquer) to compute $\widehat{F}(r Q)$ and $\widehat{g}(r Q)$, where $0\leq r<2^d$ and $F$, $g$ are being considered as functions on $\mathbb{Z}/2^d \mathbb{Z}$, $d = \lceil \log_2 l \rceil$. That gives us $\widehat{F\ast g}(r Q) = \widehat{F}(r Q) \widehat{g}(r Q)$. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem enough to give $(F\ast g)(n Q)$.

Comment: (I mean that I can see how to modify Cooley-Tukey to compute $\widehat{F}(r Q)$ and $\widehat{g}(r Q)$ for $0\leq r<2^d$ in time not much more than $O(\max(r,l) \log \max(r,l))$, as opposed to proportional to $l Q \log l Q$. Still, that doesn't seem enough.)

Comment: Are you familiar with the sparse fourier transform (e.g.  https://people.csail.mit.edu/ludwigs/papers/sp14_sfft.pdf) ?

Comment: The sparse fft assumes the transform is sparse not the function. Not obvious (to me at least) how to use it here.

Comment: Assume (as one may in many situations, e.g. when a Diophantine condition shows that one does not lose much by the approximation) that all $a_j$, $b_j$ are rationals with denominator $l$ in the interval [0,l]. Does the problem become any easier?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a partial answer. Let $k=l=N$, $n_0=0$ from now on to simplify notation. I will give an algorithm producing an approximate answer that, under some broad assumptions, can be made exact in time about $O(N^{3/2} (\log N))$. That is far from time $O(N \log N)$ or $O(N^{1+\epsilon})$ (what I desire), but it is substantially better than the trivial bound $O(N^2)$.

Again for simplicity, I will assume $a_i$, $b_i$ are rationals with denominator $N$, though that is not essential in what follows. Actually, let me renormalize things so that $a_i$, $b_i$ are integers, and we are trying to determine $(F\ast g)(n N)$ for $n=0,1,\dotsc, N-1$. (None of these assumptions are really essential, but they do simplify notation.) If you wish, you may assume that $N$ is a power of $2$. We will work with Fourier transforms defined over $\mathbb{Z}/N^2 \mathbb{Z}$.

This problem reduces to that of computing
$$h(n) = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} (f\ast g)(n N +j)$$ for $n=0,1,\dotsc, N-1$, where $f$ is a linear combination of the delta functions $\delta_{a_i}$. We can of course write $h$ as a convolution of $f$, $g$ and the characteristic function $J$ of $\{0,1,\dotsc,N-1\}$.

The inverse transform of that double convolution is $\widehat{f} \cdot \widehat{g} \cdot \widehat{J}$. Now the interesting thing is that $\widehat{J}$ is concentrated in the interval $\lbrack -N,N \rbrack$. It is basically a Dirichlet kernel normalized at scale $N$. Of course one of the issues with the Dirichlet kernel is that it doesn't decay that rapidly; if only it basically vanished outside $I_C = \lbrack - C N,C N\rbrack$, we would be done.

It does seem to me that one can compute the restriction of $\widehat{f}$ and
$\widehat{g}$ to $I_C$ in time $O(C N \log(N^2)) = O(N \log N)$ using a
modified Cooley-Tukey algorithm. Now, if we simply replace $\widehat{J}$ by its
restriction to $I_C$, we get an algorithm that runs in time $O(N \log N)$ --
but of course it would compute $\widehat{f}\cdot \widehat{g} \cdot
\widehat{J}_{|I_C}$
rather than $\widehat{f}\cdot \widehat{g} \cdot
\widehat{J}$.

What we can do is replace $J$ by an approximation $J_M$, equal to $J$
outside $\{0,\dotsc,M-1\} \cup \{N-M,\dotsc,N-1\}$, say. We can take $J_M$
to be a discrete approximation to the integral of a function of the form
$$\jmath_M(x) = \int_0^x \left(- \frac{N}{M} \phi\left(\frac{N}{M} t\right)
+ \frac{N}{M} \phi\left(\frac{N}{M} (1-t)\right)\right) dt$$
for $\phi$ a bump function with support on $\lbrack 0,1\rbrack$ and very
fast decay (say, $\widehat{\phi}(t) = O(e^{-\sqrt{t}})$, as is the case for
a standard choice of $\phi$. Then $\widehat{J_M}$ will be all but supported
on $I_{C N^2 L^2/M} = \lbrack -C N^2 L^2/M, C N^2 L^2/M\rbrack$, where $L = \log N$,
and we can truncate
it to such an interval with a total error of size $o(1/N)$, or even
$O(1/N^{10})$.
(Either should be enough; for instance, if we expect an integer as an answer
at the very end, an error $<1/2$ can be eliminated by truncation.
An error $<1/2$ has size $<1/2N$ relative to a result that is
$\leq N$, obviously.) 
We can compute $\widehat{f}\cdot \widehat{g} \cdot
\widehat{J_M}_{|I_{C N^2 L^2/M}} \sim
\widehat{f}\cdot \widehat{g} \cdot \widehat{J_M}$ in time $O(C M L^2 N)$.
Then, applying a modified Cooley-Tukey algorithm again, we obtain
rather than $f\ast g\ast J_M$.

Now, the difference between $f\ast g\ast J_M$ and $f\ast g\ast J$, taken
over all points $n N$, will consist of $O(N M)$ errors, assuming some
mild equidistribution conditions (which will hold for typical inputs
$a_i$, $b_i$). We can eliminate them by inspection in time $O(N M)$. We
set $M = L \sqrt{C N}$ and are done.

---

I will be the first to say that I am unsatisfied with the above: (a) it
takes too much time by a factor of $\sqrt{N}$; (b) it works with continuous
approximations when we should be able to proceed discretely.

Still, I hope the picture is now clearer. We are allowed to sample
$O(N)$ values of $\widehat{f}$ and $\widehat{g}$, and then use them to construct
a function of the form $\widehat{f} \cdot \widehat{g} \cdot \eta$, with support
of size $O(N)$, whose transform we can then take at $O(N)$ places.

(It would seem that we do have a
question that seems somewhat related to sparse Fourier transforms,
compressed sensing and the like, then, at least in a very rough sort of sense.)

Here is an obvious question. We have sampled $\widehat{f}$ and $\widehat{g}$
at all integer points in an interval $I_{C N^2 L^2/M}$. Can we sample them
at a better choice of points, so that only $O(N)$ or $O(N \log N)$ points
will be needed? The choice of points may depend on $f$ and $g$. (A friend points out that choosing the points to be in an arithmetic progression sounds like the worst choice possible; from that perspective, it's almost surprising that taking the points to be those in the interval $\lbrack -CN,CN\rbrack$ comes close to working.)